# loop in J language ^:

Tags: j

Assume that I have 10 random points on 2D graph, and each point is connected with a spring. So every points is converging to the center of the force for every iterations.

What I am trying to make is a loop that adds a random vector to an existing vector set after each iteration.

So it starts from

```
v=: <(? 10 2 $ 20)   NB. 10 random vectors 
n=: <(? 1 2 $ 20)    NB. new random vector
force v              NB. force function moves the vectors toward to the center 
add n                NB. add n into v, then #v = 11
force v
add n
force v
add n 
...
```

I'm still working on the force function which seems like to be not hard, but I got really stuck on the add section. Can anyone help me on this?
My final goal is to make a loop repeating add force section like 100 times

Thank you!

Comment: I suspect that you can do without the boxing. It's better to avoid boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Eelvex that the boxes seem redundant. Perhaps the following is a useful way to think about what you are trying to accomplish?

```
   new=: 2 ?@$ 20"_      NB. generates random, length 2 vector
   add=: ] , new         NB. appends new to right argument
   add^:(3) Init=: 4 2 ?@$ 20
11  9
 9 16
 9 13
 0 17
 3  3
 7 17
 6  6
```

If you have a verb `force` you could apply that at each iteration too:

```
   force=: -:            NB. example verb (halves right argument)
   force@add^:(5) Init=: 4 2 ?@$ 20   NB. 5 iterations
0.46875  0.3125
0.15625 0.53125
0.28125 0.53125
 0.5625 0.53125
0.59375 0.59375
  1.125   0.375
  0.125   2.375
   2.25     3.5
      5     9.5
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if what you want to do is to unbox `v` and `n` then `,` (Append). The way to do this is to use each=: `&.>` which uses `&.` (Under) and `>` (Open).

`, each`  Opens, performs the Append operation, then closes.

```
   v=.<(? 10 2 $ 20)
   v
+-----+
| 9 11|
| 1  4|
| 8  3|
| 3 12|
| 5  4|
| 7 11|
|10 11|
| 9 10|
| 0  8|
| 6 16|
+-----+
   n=: <(? 1 2 $ 20)
   n
+----+
|13 8|
+----+
   n , each v
+-----+
|13  8|
| 9 11|
| 1  4|
| 8  3|
| 3 12|
| 5  4|
| 7 11|
|10 11|
| 9 10|
| 0  8|
| 6 16|
+-----+
   each
&.>
```

Comment: Or apply `,` at level `0`:  `v , L:0 n`